# freeswitch esl using node js

Tags: node.js, freeswitch

I am implementing freeswitch ESL using nodejs, for which i am using [modesl](https://npmjs.org/package/modesl) module, it works fine and i can call dialplan tools using the execute function.

However execute function is an asynchronous implementation in modesl module of nodejs.

What i need is a synchronous call so that when i call execute function the execution should wait till freeswitch finishes executing that application.

In the below code sample i get the output "ivr finished" before the playback gets finished.

```
exports.process_ivr = function (conn, id)
{
    conn.execute('answer');
    conn.execute('playback','/root/before.wav');
    console.log('ivr finished');
};
```

As per [modesl](https://npmjs.org/package/modesl) there is no asynchronous way of calling freeswitch commands, is there any other way to implement this using nodejs?

Comment: node.js use 1 thread, so synchronous function will make `modesl` serve 1 client at a time? I think you can detect if execute is finish via callback `conn.execute('playback','/root/before.wav', function () {console.log('ivr finished')})`;

Comment: that didn't helped,it simply logs at the end of call. Assume i am sending 4 playback commands one after the other then all these commands are queued to ESL. An ideal case would be using play_and_get_digits and handling different response on dtmf value.

Comment: But you can check dtmf then call next `execute` in callback, then we have callback inside callback. Well it is hard to read :) but it is asynchronous.

Comment: I think the topic starter needs to read a good book about how Node works, about event loop, async IO and callbacks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
 conn.execute('answer',function(){
    conn.execute('playback','/root/before.wav',function(){
      console.log('ivr finished');
    });
 });
```